# Can we clear the SQLite ? if yes then tell me how?

Tags: android

I am working on the SQLite database and i want to clear DB after fetching data from it. Kindly guide me on how can I clear/empty DB after fetching data from it.

Comment: You can delete all tables,views from database after fetching data or try this context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

Answer (score 1):

There are two option to clear the table from the database

**Firstly**

If you wan to delete the data on specific row you need to add this code in the database class

```
   public boolean deleteSpecificOrder(int id, String table_name)
  {
    return db.delete(table_name, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
  }
```

and add the below code when you want to perform this action

```
  db.deleteSpecificOrder(id, "table_orders");
```

**Secondly**

If you want to delete all the data from th table then you just need  to add below code into your database

```
public void clearDatabase(String TABLE_NAME) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}
```

and then add the below line where you want to perform that action

```
 db.clearDatabase("table_food_items");
```

I Hope that will help you